# Clicking on a list element to get an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Lets say I have a list of links:

```
<a id="home" href="#"> home link </a><br/>
<a id="list1" href="#"> some text1 </a><br/> 
<a id="list2" href="#"> some text2 </a><br/> 
<a id="list3"> href="#"> some text3 </a><br/> 
<a id="list4" href="#"> some text4 </a><br/
<a id="list5" href="#"> some text5 </a><br/>
<a id="list sails" href="#"> sails link </a><br/>
```

and if some list link is clicked I get an alert with its text.

I wrote a script but it isn't right, it looks like this:

```
function lunch(){
  alert( $(this).text()) }
```

for

```
<a id="listn" href="#" onclick="lunch()"> some text5 </a><br/>
```

How to do this in jQuery or just JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('a[id^=list]').click(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

This will work for all links that has an id starting with 'list'. if you want it to work for all links change the selector to `$('a')`.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the node instance into the lunch function.

```
< a id="listn" href="#" onclick="lunch(this)"> some text5 < /a>
```

And use this as argument

```
function lunch(node){ alert( $(node).text()) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<div id="links">
<a id="home" href="#">home link</a>
<a id="list1" class="list" href="#">some text1</a>
<a id="list2" class="list" href="#">some text2</a>
<a id="list3" class="list" href="#">some text3</a>
<a id="list4" class="list" href="#">some text4</a>
<a id="list5" class="list" href="#">some text5</a>
</div>
```

with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#links a").click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

or to restrict it to just the list ilinks:

```
$("a.list").click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
  return false;
});
```

You'll note that I put a class in there instead of using an attribute selector, which generally isn't advised. Also, by the principles of [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) you should add your event handlers this way rather than using `onclick` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to give each one a class, e.g `

```
$(function()
{
    $('.lunchable').click(function()
    {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```